# HTML5 "date" input format, autofill with current day

Tags: html, date

I'm using the HTML5 date format, and I wanted to autofill it with the current date, but allow it to be changed.

Previously with a simple textbox, I could use PHP to bring back the current date on the form but still have it editable, as such:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo date('d / m / Y'); ?>"/>
```

But when using `date` as the input type, the PHP value is overwritten and replaced with `dd/mm/yyyy` instead.

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date('d / m / Y'); ?>"/>
```

[Tinygrab screenshot example](http://grab.by/Boss)

Any ideas how to use HTML5 new input types but still be able to provide a default value?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#date-state-(type=date): _“The value attribute, if specified and not empty, must have a value that is a [valid date string](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-date-string).”_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set it via JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('DateField').valueAsDate = new Date();
```

EDIT:

It can also be done via PHP if you alter the way you're displaying the date.

```
<input type="date" value ="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>"
```

Edit2: Fixed the code so it actually works.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use JS, but your second option doesn't work either as it seems PHP is overwritten by the HTML5 date attribute.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Just add echo and format the default value as year-month-date

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HudMe/6/)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the echo. It won't add the date, it'll always be overwritten by the default dd/mm/yyyy